# Has_many though -- how to add a model in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Say, I have these models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :account_games, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :games, :through => :account_games
    end

    class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :account_games, :dependent => :destroy
      has_many :accounts, :through => :account_games
    end

    class AccountGame < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :account
      belongs_to :game

      validates :account, presence: true
      validates :game, presence: true
    end
```

I know I could do this in Rails 3:

```
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
@accountgame = @account.account_games.build(:game => Game.first, :score => 100)
@accountgame.save
```

Update:

```
# or
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
@account.games << Game.first
# what's next? any other setting required and if so where?
```

That is, I already have a game and I want to add it to an account. How can I do this in Rails 4?

Comment: Should be the same... are you getting an error?

Comment: did you tried `@account.account_games << @accountgame`?. You may need to use the `:autosave => true` option, so that ActiveRecord save the relations automatically.

Comment: @yeyo, in which model?

Comment: @dinjas, yes, account.account_games "is invalid"

Comment: @Johshi is your `account_game` valid? E.g. if you do `ag = AccountGame.new(game: Game.first, score: 100)`, is `ag.valid? == true`?

Comment: And if not, what does `puts ag.errors` in the console show you?

Comment: @dinjas, where do I get "account.id" for AccountGame if "account" hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Is there a validation on the `account` for `AccountGame`? You might try setting the [`inverse_of`](module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) and see if that fixes your issue. E.g. `has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :account` and `has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :game`

Comment: @dinjas, is which model?

Comment: In `Account` model: `has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :account`, in `Game` model: `has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :game`. If that doesn't work, and you have any validations in any of those models, you'll prob want to add the validations to the code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Rails are you on exactly? I'm not able to recreate your problem with a new Rails app under `4.2.5.1`.

Migrations:

`Account` migration:

```
class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
 end
end
```

`Game` migration:

```
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`AccountGame` migration:

```
class CreateAccountGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :account_games do |t|
      t.references :account
      t.references :game
      t.integer :score
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

`Account` model (app/models/account.rb):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :games, through: :account_games
end
```

`Game` model (app/models/game.rb):

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :accounts, through: :account_games
end
```

`AccountGame` model (app/models/account_game.rb):

```
class AccountGame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :game

  validates :account, presence: true
  validates :game, presence: true
end
```

Using it:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5.1)
>> g = Game.create
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "games" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-09-20 03:31:41.484101"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-20 03:31:41.484101"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Game id: 2, created_at: "2016-09-20 03:31:41", updated_at: "2016-09-20 03:31:41">
>> a = Account.new
=> #<Account id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> a.account_games.build(game: Game.first, score: 100)
  Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games"  ORDER BY "games"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<AccountGame id: nil, account_id: nil, game_id: 1, score: 100, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> a.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "accounts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2016-09-20 03:32:02.532976"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-20 03:32:02.532976"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "account_games" ("game_id", "score", "account_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["game_id", 1], ["score", 100], ["account_id", 2], ["created_at", "2016-09-20 03:32:02.535031"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-20 03:32:02.535031"]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
=> true
>> a.account_games
  AccountGame Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "account_games".* FROM "account_games" WHERE "account_games"."account_id" = ?  [["account_id", 2]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<AccountGame id: 2, account_id: 2, game_id: 1, score: 100, created_at: "2016-09-20 03:32:02", updated_at: "2016-09-20 03:32:02">]>
```

You can also do:

```
>> a.account_games.count
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "account_games" WHERE "account_games"."account_id" = ?  [["account_id", 2]]
=> 1

>> a.games << Game.first
  Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "games".* FROM "games"  ORDER BY "games"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "account_games" ("account_id", "game_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["account_id", 2], ["game_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-09-20 04:52:07.058592"], ["updated_at", "2016-09-20 04:52:07.058592"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
  Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "account_games" ON "games"."id" = "account_games"."game_id" WHERE "account_games"."account_id" = ?  [["account_id", 2]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Game id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16", updated_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16">, #    <Game id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16", updated_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16">, #<Game id: 1, created_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16", updated_at: "2016-09-20 03:24:16">]>
>> a.account_games.count
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "account_games" WHERE "account_games"."account_id" = ?  [["account_id", 2]]
=> 2
```

I'm assuming your `Game` is valid? E.g. `Game.first.valid? == true`

Comment: I have an array of games, that's why I'm doing this "a.accounts << my_games", but it says "account_games is invalid" in account.errors. it's rails 4.0

Comment: I added another example of what I think you're doing at the end of my answer. Are there any other validations in any of those 3 models that you didn't show? Are you using the correct syntax (asking because your comment ^^ doesn't seem to be accurate compared to what you had in your question)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.0.9

```
@account = Account.new(params[:user])
account_game_datas = [{game_id: 1, score: 100}, {game: 2, score: 110}]
@accountgame = @account.account_games.build(account_game_datas)
@accountgame.save
```

It works the same as rails4.

You can use NEST by these:

```
# model
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :games, :through => :account_games
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_games
end

# controller
params[:user][:account_games_attributes] = [{game_id: 1, score: 100}, {game: 2, score: 110}]
@account = Account.create(user_params)

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(..., account_games_attributes: [:game_id, :score])
end
```